# Include a .txt file in a .h in C++?

Tags: xcode, gcc, applet, header-files, include

I have a number of places where I need to re-use some template  code. Many classes need these items

In a .h could I do something like:

```
#include <xxx.txt>
```

and place all of this code in the .txt and just have it included?

Something like a PHP include!

Does gcc allow this?

Comment: Also, since I'm guessing that you might be slightly new to C, note that when you say #include <foo> then gcc looks in the include path for system directories, whereas #include "foo" (with quotation marks) searches in the same directory as your local file. See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html

Answer (score 6):

You can include any file you care to name.

EDIT: You could also have just tried it.  Worst case?  You have an "undo" on your hands.

Comment: @Chris - I did using a .inc file extension and it did not work for me. GCC complained about missing items.

Comment: Can you post an exact error message?  It seems to me like probably your .inc file just has some invalid syntax.

Remember, any file you #include can contain only valid C++ code.

Answer (score 3):

don't forget to wrap your various items in #DEFINE's and #IFDEF's to make sure you aren't redefining junk all over the place for your compiler to bitch about...

Answer (score 0):

As Chris says, you can include any file you care to name.

In practice it's best to avoid arbitrary file extensions - I'd suggest 'SomeFile.inl' over 'SomeFile.txt', as your IDE of choice is more likely to apply correct syntax highlighting to the file when you open it.